# How to write, update, and save a CSV in AWS S3 using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, csv, aws-lambda, csv-write-stream

I am in the process of automating an AWS Textract flow where files gets uploaded to S3 using an app (that I have already done), a lambda function gets triggered, extracts the forms as a CSV, and saves it in the same bucket.

I have started this with just a Textract formula for all the text in the image, with the result being a .txt file. Below is my code:

```
def InvokeTextract(bucketName, documentKey):
    print('Loading InvokeTextract')
    # Call Amazon Textract
    response = textract.detect_document_text(
        Document={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucketName,
                'Name': documentKey
            }
        })

    Textractoutput = ''

    # Print detected text
    for item in response['Blocks']:
        if item['BlockType'] == 'LINE':
            Textractoutput += item['Text'] + '\n'

    return Textractoutput

def writeOutputToS3Bucket(textractData, bucketName, createdS3Document):
    print('Loading writeOutputToS3Bucket')
    generateFilePath = os.path.splitext(createdS3Document)[0] + '.txt'
    s3.put_object(Body=textractData, Bucket=bucketName, Key=generateFilePath)
    print('Generated ' + generateFilePath)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        Textractoutput = InvokeTextract(bucket, key)
        writeOutputToS3Bucket(Textractoutput, bucket, key)

        return 'Processed'
```

And this work just fine, but if I want to get key-value pairs, this isn't helpful. So, I tried to use another code for CSV. From my local drive, I was able to do that. Below is part of my code:

```
import trp #Local Module
import csv

doc = Document(response) #from TRP

with open('aws_doc.csv', mode='w') as aws_field_file:
    field_write = csv.writer(aws_field_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    field_write.writerow(["Key", "Value"])

    for page in doc.pages:
        for field in page.form.fields:
            # This will write it as your <key>, <value>
            field_write.writerow([field.key, field.value])
```

But when I am trying to code this using Lambda, I am not getting the results (i.e. a CSV file in my bucket). I read about it and I found I needed to create a tmp file, but that was a bit unclear. I went with this code below:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucketName = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    documentKey = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')

    #S3 client
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    # Amazon Textract client
    textract = boto3.client('textract')

    # Get AWS Textract Response for Forms
    response = textract.analyze_document(
        Document={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucketName,
                'Name': documentKey
            }
        },
        FeatureTypes = ["FORMS"])

    # Using custom trp module
    doc = Document(response)

    import csv 

    temp_csv_file = csv.writer(open("/tmp/csv_file.csv", "w+"))
    temp_csv_file.writerow(["Key", "Value"])

    for page in doc.pages:
        for field in page.form.fields:
            # This will write it as your <key>, <value>
            temp_csv_file.writerow([field.key, field.value])

    bucketName.upload_file('/tmp/csv_file.csv', 'textractData.csv')
```

Is my code correct? Am I missing a step in there?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
bucketName.upload_file('/tmp/csv_file.csv', 'textractData.csv')
```

Try

```
s3.upload_file('/tmp/csv_file.csv', bucketName, 'textractData.csv')
```

Comment: I am wondering if the csv file was saved to disk. Can you read read it and print it to the console? (right before bucketName.upload_file)

Comment: For case with concurrent invocations of the lambda - won't it create collisions using same '/tmp/csv_file.csv'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this unless you need to create a temp file.

`s3.put_object(Body='contents', Bucket='bucket-name', Key='outputTextFileName')`

get this to work by implementing as below:

```py
def writeCSV(csvData):
    body = StringIO() #because s3 require bytes or file like obj
    writer = csv.writer(body)
    for item in csvData:
        writer.writerow(item)
    csvS3 = body.getvalue()
    return csvS3

contents = writeCSV('provide csv data')
s3.put_object(Body=contents, Bucket='bucket-name', Key='outputTextFileName')
```

- S3 has to be defined previously using `s3 = boto3.client('s3')`
- Bucket must be existing in the same
  region as to that of lambda function